# Which JRE should I use for a stand alone application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've taken some java classes to learn programming, but I haven't actually built a fully functional java application. I want to build a fairly simple form-based application for my own uses on a single pc with a MySQL back end (using Eclipse as the IDE). So, I went to create the new project and I'm a little stumped on which JRE to choose. And a quick Google search just confused me more. There are 3 choices:
1. Use an execution environment JRE (with a list of options that seems to default to OSGi/Minimum-1.2
2. Use a project specific JRE (has a dropdown with a single option: 'jre1.8.0_31')
3. Use default JRE (currently 'jre1.8.0_31')

Does it matter which JRE I choose? I don't want to go through the process of building a whole application then discover I can't run it as a stand alone application because I chose the wrong thing here.

Sorry about my noob question, but I'm just trying to get up and running and then  hopefully I will be good to go.

Comment: Which JRE will the users of your application have? And 1.8.0_31 is a little old now.

Comment: Use whatever version that meets your feature requirements. If you want to support Apple products use JDK 6, if you want to have diamond operators. binary literals, string switch statements, catching multiple exceptions in a single line, `_`'s as a numeral seperator use JDK 7, if you want to have lambdas, streams use JDK 8, if you want to run the latest and greatest use JDK 9.

Comment: If you don't know what you want, I would recommend the latest stable JDK 8 release (JDK 9 is still a little new and I would let Oracle iron out any bugs before using it).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what is the latest version? I opened my Java Control Panel and confirmed that I have "Check for Updates Automatically" checked. Do I have to do something else to get it updated?

Comment: @MichaelT: that's really a new question, but: recentish updates of Oracle Java 8 on Windows install into separate directories `c:\Program Files [(x86)]\Java\<jxx>1.8.0_<version>` and put copies under `c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java` so that just running `java` from commandline (or start etc) gets the latest version, but Eclipse configures (and examines) the real path. In Preferences/Java/InstalledJREs use Add to create a new entry pointing to the new `c:\program files\java\jre<version>` or `jdk<version>\jre` and select that for workspace, project(s), or run/debug config(s) as you wish.

Comment: BTW although you need to choose a JRE/environment when you create a project, it's easy to change it later if you want -- as long as all Java language features you use in your code, like those mentioned by @van, are compatible with the environment you choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to develop your own applications, consider using JDK instead. It will as well provide you support for running applications.

I am currently using build "1.8.0_144"; however, you can get the latest release at [Oracle's web page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/2133151)